# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Error

Tags: apex, soql, class

Method : This just one method of the class I am testing from Dev console

```
public Employee__c getEmployeeDetails()
{
    Employee__c emp = null;
    emp = [SELECT field1__c, field2__c, field3__c FROM Employee__c WHERE Accountid__c ='001L000000ogtry' limit 1];

    return emp;
}
```

Dev console :

```
 classname cc = new Classname();
 cc.getEmployeeDetails();
```

The SELECT query returns records when queried individually.

Any help on why it's occurring.
Account id is being taken from url . Here I have hardcoded just to test.

Comment: Does your code with the Hardcoded Account Id work?  Nothing in this code should cause this error as far as I can tell.  Perhaps the code you were using to get the Account Id from the URL is the real culprit?

Comment: @doug The actual code is -- emp = [SELECT field1__c, field2__c, field3__c FROM Employee__c WHERE Accountid__c =: currentRecordId limit 1]; I am getting value of currentRecordId in system.debug. So , that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Does the error give you a line number?  Nothing I see in this code should give this error.

Comment: Try to run the query in query editor and see what you get. Do you get any records?

Comment: @SfdcBat- Yes , records are shown in Query editor

Comment: @AdrianLarson - As I mentioned , I had hardcoded just to test the method . Otherwise I am holding the  value in currentRecordId . This value is getting queried correctly in the class.

Comment: How are you passing `currentRecordId` to your class? It doesn't appear to me to be in context to your class and you've not defined it as a variable in what you've posted.

Comment: @crmprogdev - For the sake of testing in Dev console , I had hard coded the id. Otherwise I'm querying that initially in the class

Comment: can you post your whole class and what exactly you are executing in dev console?

Comment: @AnuragA- I am just calling the method from Dev console  I have written that in the question description .

Comment: @SFDCRookie How are you getting the value from the URL? It sounds like that's where your problem probably is.

Comment: @MikeChale - That shouldn't be the problem I guess . Moreover here I am testing with hard coded one . However , it's working if I change the method to a static one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running this from dev console, before running your query, you're essentially saying:

```
sObject sOb = null;
```

rather than:

```
sObject sOb = new sObject();
```

It appears to me that you're then assigning the results of a query to a `null` sObject. Now, if you removed the assignment of the `null` and simply wrote:

```
 sObject sOb = [yourquerystring with valid recordID];
```

then I'd expect you wouldn't be having the problem that's occurring from having initialized your object to `null`. Instead, you'd be initializing it to the results of the query as it should be. If your query didn't return a record, you'd still get an exception, but it wouldn't be a null pointer exception.

I believe the above explains why you're getting the null pointer exception.

Comment: Using `sOb` is a bit of a humorous abbreviation. Not sure if that's intentional...at least is's not as bad as `std` for `StandardController` but still.

Comment: @AdrianLarson It's a collaborative community. Feel free to edit if you'd like. ;) I'm just not especially fond of Mr foo and Ms bar.

Comment: I prefer the more descriptive `record`. I would only edit your post if you have a factual error, or perhaps if your code wouldn't compile for an obvious reason.  That said, double assignment should be fine barring the involvement of `final`, I'd think.

Comment: @crmprogdev-Adding another observation . If I change the method to static one , it's executing perfectly . Any reason why so?

Comment: In the context you're calling it, it probably should be. From Apex Docs "A static method is used as a utility method, and it never depends on the value of an instance member variable." You created a new instance of your class just before you called the method from Dev Console.

Answer (score -1):

This issue was caused due to one field value being null for one of the object records. Thank you all for your inputs.